# In cellformatting e.value property is null when using BindingList

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindinglist

I am new to datagridview. I have datagrid cellformatting event. when this event is fired e.Value is coming as null.
if i bind the datasource with Bindinglist then e.Value is Null if i bind the directly with the IList, i am getting proper value.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   IList<MyClass> myClassList = new List<MyClass>();
   myClassList.Add(new MyClass());
   myClassList.Add(new MyClass());

   BindingList<MyClass> myClassDS = new BindingList<MyClass>(myClassList);
   var source = new BindingSource(myClassDS, null);

   dataGridView1.DataSource = source; //e.Value is null here
   //dataGridView.DataSource = myClassList; //This is working fine
}

private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
   //e.Value is null. here i should get current cell value.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value
```

Comment: This also coming null value

Comment: When do you change the formatting of the cell. If the even triggers before the form is actually loaded, you would always have null.

Comment: the formatting event is automatically triggered when datasource is set to the grid

Comment: Basicly, you are trying to get a value from an object that isn't yet created. The form is not loaded yet...

Comment: Try to move the assigning of the datasource to a separate function, which will be called in the form_load.